# MySQL SELECT where common foreign key among many

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure how to accurately summarize the problem I'm having in one sentence, but it is fairly simple to describe (below). Here are three tables associated with foreign keys on the last table:

tbl_village:

```
villageID | village_name  
   1      | Happy Village  
   2      | Sad Village
```

tbl_setting:

```
settingID|setting_name  
   32    |   Chill
   33    |   Hyper
```

tbl_neighbourhood:

```
neighbourhoodID|settingID_fk|villageID_fk|neighbourhood_name  
      53       |    32      |     1      |      Balls 
      54       |    32      |     1      |    Peacefull   
      55       |    32      |     1      |    SunnyBrook  
      56       |    33      |     1      |   Rainbow Lane  
      57       |    33      |     1      |    High Five  
      58       |    32      |     2      |   Fungus square  
      59       |    32      |     2      |    Mountains
```

What I would like to do is query tbl_neighbourhood with any number of villageIDs and select the settingID_fk where the villages have common settingID_fks

So far I have a very basic query:

```
SELECT s.settingID
       ,s.setting_name
FROM   tbl_neighbourhood n JOIN tbl_setting s ON s.settingID = n.settingID_fk
WHERE  n.villageID_fk = 1
       OR
       n.villageID_fk = 2
GROUP BY s.settingID
```

This query returns:

```
settingID|setting_name
    32   |    Chill
    33   |    Hyper
```

But I want only the settingIDs that the specified villages have in common, so I want this result:

```
settingID|setting_name
    32   |     Chill
```

I've tried using different joins, but not having success. I would rather get the desired result from a query and not have to manually process the result with a server-side language after-the-fact. I feel like this is a simple problem for someone who is more adept at MySQL...?

Thanks for any assistance in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to move the conditions to the `having` clause:

```
SELECT s.settingID, s.setting_name
FROM   tbl_neighbourhood n JOIN
       tbl_setting s
       ON s.settingID = n.settingID_fk
GROUP BY s.settingID, s.setting_name
HAVING sum(n.villageID_fk = 1) > 0 and
       sum(n.villageID_fk = 2) > 0;
```

Each conditions counts the number of rows that match one of the villages.  These guarantee that both are present.

You can also write this as:

```
SELECT s.settingID, s.setting_name
FROM   tbl_neighbourhood n JOIN
       tbl_setting s
       ON s.settingID = n.settingID_fk
WHERE  n.villageID_fk in (1, 2)
GROUP BY s.settingID, s.setting_name
HAVING count(distinct n.villageID_fk) = 2;
```

Comment: Ended up using your first solution. Your query allows for easiest  dynamic & specific villageID_fk clauses

Answer (score 0):

You want to `JOIN` neighbourhood against itself:

```
SELECT s.settingID, s.setting_name
FROM   tbl_neighbourhood n1
  JOIN tbl_neighbourhood n2
  ON (n1.settingID_fk = n2.settingID_fk
  AND n1.villageID_fk < n2.villageID_fk)
JOIN tbl_settings s ON s.settingID = n1.settingID_fk
WHERE  n1.villageID_fk IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY s.settingID
```

This will fetch all villages, and for each of them check the settings of all subsequent villages; when two settings are identical, they are reported. Or you can also do, more explicitly:

> But I want only the settingIDs that the specified villages have in common

```
SELECT s.settingID, s.setting_name
FROM   tbl_neighbourhood a
  JOIN tbl_neighbourhood b
  ON (a.settingID_fk = b.settingID_fk
  AND a.villageID_fk = 1
  AND b.villageID_fk = 2)
JOIN tbl_settings s ON s.settingID = a.settingID_fk
GROUP BY s.settingID
```

This is much more efficient if you have lots of villages, and the neighbourhood is indexed by villageID_fk, since the query optimizer will first fetch village1 from A, then village2 from B, and from these two small sets of rows build the query proper.

## SQL Fiddle

Here you can find a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3007c/2) to play with in order to test different settings. [This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0d3b/1) is the same, with indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to hard code the foreign keys in the query. Here's a simple query that satisfies your need without having to hard code the FKs in the query and will work with more than the two mentioned villages or settings:

```
SELECT s.settingID, s.setting_name
FROM   tbl_neighbourhood n JOIN tbl_setting s ON s.settingID = n.settingID_fk
GROUP BY s.settingID, s.setting_name
HAVING count(distinct n.villageID_fk) > 1;
```

Pretty much Gordon gave the correct answer for your data. I just modified it to work with any data. His won't work with more than two villages or more than two common settings (the count should be > 1 not = 2).
Cheers,
koshera